# Referencing java class variable from log4j2.xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 and using log4j2.xml for its configuration. I am configuring the `PatternLayout` and its pattern currently is `%d [%t] %p %c - %m%n`. It is the same value as `PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN` defined in log4j2 core Javadoc. So is it possible to reference this variable instead of copy the value into the xml?

My full log4j2.xml is attached for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="consoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %p %c - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least the following choices:

1. Use an environment variable, like: `<PatternLayout pattern="${env:MY_PATTERN}" />`. And define the variable before the logger is initialized, with: `System.setProperty("MY_PATTERN",PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN)`.
2. Or, if you need the pattern to be defined at runtime based on some conditions, you can define your own `Logger` class with a custom appender, something like (this is using the file appender, but you will get the idea):

   ```
   public class MyLogClass {

    private static Logger log =  Logger.getLogger(MyLogClass.class);
    private static boolean initFlag = false;

    private static void initLogger(){
      log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);

      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      Date date = new Date();

      RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender();
      appender.setAppend(true);
      appender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
      appender.setMaxBackupIndex(1);
      appender.setFile("my_log_file-" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".log");

      PatternLayout layOut = new PatternLayout();
      layOut.setConversionPattern(PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN);
      appender.setLayout(layOut);

     log.addAppender(appender);
    }

    public static Logger getLogger(){
      if(initFlag == false){
         initLogger();
         initFlag = true;
         return MyLogClass.log;
      } else {
         return MyLogClass.log;
      }
    }
   }
   ```

Then use it like:

```
LogClass.getLogger().debug("test");
```